# not able to execute “sh” comands in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins

WHen i tried executing "sh" commands in the Jenkins Pipeline, i face the below error,

```
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified


[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have installed CYGWIN and set up the shell path of jenkins to be "C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe", but still it is not able to pick the "sh" command.

Please help in fixing this issue.

Comment: You did not show in your question the exact command which you used to set up the path, nor how you then invoke the `sh` command. BTW, does it work if you don't rely on the PATH variable, but specify the path explicitly on invocation of sh?

Comment: I re-started the jenkins, it started recognizing CYGWIN and i am able to execute the shell commands.